# Psycopg3 selecting null values

Tags: python, psycopg3

I have started migrating some Python code from using psycopg2 to pscopyg3. It appears there is a change in how null values are accepted as query parameters in the newer version. Based on a read of the [documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/params.html) for this topic in psycopg3 there isn't any mention of how to deal with null values.

Below is a simplified example of my use case that worked fine in psycopg2

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mock_table WHERE var_1 is %s", [None])
```

And the below error is produced now in psycopg3

> psycopg.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "$1" LINE 1:

> SELECT * FROM mock_table WHERE var_1 is $1

Answer (score 1):

Filtering by `NULL` is not compatible with psycopg's [server-side binding behaviour](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/from_pg2.html#you-cannot-use-is-s).

You can use `IS DISTINCT FROM` instead, or `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`, as is now documented:

```py
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col IS DISTINCT FROM %s', (None,))
```

Both of the general alternatives proposed in the docs also work:

```py
# Use psycopg's formatting tools.
cur.execute(psycopg.sql.SQL('select * from tbl where col is {}'.format('NULL')))

# Use client-side binding
cur = psycopg.ClientCursor(conn)
cur.execute('select * from tbl where col is %s', (None,))
```